# Psycopg2 thread hang

Tags: python, freeze, psycopg2

I have a multi-threaded python daemon where each thread reads data from csv files and write to database in batches. Few times the threads writing to database running in same box end up in hung state. I have checked pg_stat_activity and ensured that the thread is not hung in SQL INSERT. I could see a raw connection in netstat output. My guess is that the hang is happening in psycopg2 'connect' call.

Surprisingly the thread came out of hung state on doing an 'strace'. As I am not able to reproduce the issue, no further data points are available.

Any similar issues reported before ?

Comment: What do you mean by "hung" state?  Sounds like you just had one thread take longer than expected.

Comment: Hung means it is alive but is not executing. It stayed in that state for days and an strace to the process resulted in the thread to come out of that state.

Comment: Anoop, you have open a bug report in the psycopg2 tracker but never replied to that. I need more information to fix the problem: please register to http://psycopg.lighthouseapp.com/projects/62710/tickets/112 and give us some feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Reviving an old question, but did you ever get the answer to this?

I'm now facing something similar, where I need to open a SSH tunnel first (not sure if that matters), and then `psycopg2.connect` only when running in a multi threaded environment.  Single thread works ok.